# Convert Color and Size attribute dropdown values to Button links

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created configurable products based upon Size and Color attribute. When I access the product detail page, I see there are two dropdowns, one for Color and other for Size. Now I want to change that from Dropdown to Button Links.

[image: Size button links should be display instead of Dropdown]
[image: Color button links should be display instead of Dropdown]

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party extension for achieving this, like this:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gala-color-swatches-free-1-1.html

Or

please follow the below blog:

http://www.magetraining.com/blog/how-to-set-up-configurable-swatches-in-magento-versions-1-9-x/

Answer (score 0):

You can Follow this link :
https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-and-manage-configurable-swatches.html#gref

For size, follow the same steps mentioned in above link and do the following settings in admin panel:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have followed all the steps which are mentioned in above link. But still, they are shown in the dropdown. I want to show it in Square boxes.

Comment: Answer edited, check again.